# bootstrap-fileinput with ASP.NET MVC - Form Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-file-upload

I wanted to use this plugin (bootstrap-fileinput) to do some simple file upload. Now I'm pretty sure I removed the most to keep a simple file upload via form submit.

```js
script type="text/javascript">
    $("#input-id").fileinput({ 'maxFileCount' : 1,'showUpload': false, 'showPreview': false, 'uploadAsync': false, 'showRemove': false, 'showClose': false, 'showCaption': false });
</script>
```

Still it seems to wanna upload something Asynchronously. It throws a javascript error: Error error not found undefined

Looking in the network log of chrome I see it wants to do this:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
`http://localhost:64251/File/UploadFile`

Why does it do this? What am I forgetting? I just want to upload the file data when I click the submit button and let it then process everything by the controller. Not asynchronously and not via ajax.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have a method named `UploadFile()` in `FileController`?

Comment: There is no controller with that name.  The field is in a form that will send the data to the profile controller to the update profile method.  Why does it call this?